# Wingpanel doesn't changing color when change it wallpaper

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel

I just installed elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera right and I notice that wingpanel font color isn't changing to black when I define a white wallpaper. As I remember, it this doesn't happened in other versions. Does someone know if it is due to new version or something weird happened with my installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It looks like something weird happened with your installation.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, it seems to be a gtk problem. Looks here https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/292

Comment: It seems you are right.